# Can I get a Facebook resemblance Post Template?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Can I get a Facebook resemblance Post Template?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Firebug in Firefox
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/

Then with the inspector feature, replicate the styles used.

Comment: I also use Firebug, but if you're on Chrome or IE, just press F12.

Comment: Ah, or ctrl+shift+i will bring up the same in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what you need.

http://codepen.io/danelips/pen/Fkciq `Facebook post`